# Not able to get response of clubhouse api/Complete api

Tags: api, postman, web-api-testing, clubhouse

i am trying to get a response of clubhosue api -https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2651915/TzCQa6Wx#04f04055-df52-4b3f-9136-9ac8bd30b36b

i have successfully run the **check** api but unable to run **complete** api i am attaching image of the following if some can help with this it will be helpful

i am checking the api by postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj7Bg.png)

Answer (score 1):

Clubhouse doesn't have any official API yet, and these are [private API](https://apiacademy.co/2015/04/api-strategy-201-private-apis-vs-open-apis/).

this API is not working anymore. until someone update it

by the way please read this community guideline